# Printing escape character

Tags: c++, escaping

When I am given `"d""\"/""b"`, I need to print out the statement character for character. (d, b, a slash, a backslash, and 5 quotes) in C++.  The only errors that show now are the lines `if(i.at(j)="\\")` and `else if(i.at(j)="\"")`. Also, how should the outside double apostrophes be excluded?

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 using namespace std;

 int main (int argc, const char* argv[] )
 {
     string i= argv[1];
     for (int j=0; j>=sizeof(i)-1; j++)
     {
         if(i.at(j)=='\\')
         {
         cout << '\\';
         }
         else if(i.at(j)=='\"')
         {
         cout << '\"';
         }
         else
         {
         cout << i.at(j);
         }
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

*Revision - OK so I corrected the double apostrophes to single apostrophes but the code always aborts on me.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside double apostrophes be excluded?"

Comment: if(i.at(j)="\\") -- you know you are doing an assignment right?  Use ==

Comment: It's only supposed to print 5 double apostrophes instead of 7

Comment: what kind of error does it throw when it bombs? Or is it a silent error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've goofed up your equality testing (`==`, not `=`).

Also, start at index 1, and go until 1 less (2 less, by index) than the length of the string.

Comment: what do you mean index 1. could you explain further?

Comment: The opening quote is at index 0 of the string.

Comment: okay i've corrected as shown above, but if i add the line `cout << sizeof(i);` it outputs 4 no matter what I type in prompt

Comment: That's because the `sizeof` operator is giving you the size of the reference/pointer. Perhaps you want `strlen()` or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string::at()` returns a `char`, not a `std::string`, so you need to use character literals (delimited by single quotes, `'`), not string literals (delimited by double quotes, `"`).  e.g.,

```
i.at(j) == '\\'
```

Note also that you are using *assignment* (`=`) and not *equality comparison* (`==`) in your `if` statements (this is a common, pernicious error).

Comment: The code aborts on me even if I corrected it.  I edited the post; could you help me again?

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop `for (int j=0; j>=sizeof(i)-1; j++)` is incorrect for two reasons.

First, you would want a less-than or less-than-or-equal comparison in your loop. As it's written now, `j` starts at zero, which is not greater than `sizeof(i)-1`. Thus your loop aborts immediately.

Second, `sizeof(i)` is not what you want to compare against anyway. That expression gives the size of a string object, not the size of the actual string contained by the object. You want `i.size()`

With these changes, your loop would be `for (int j=0; j<=i.size()-1; j++)`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is unnecessary. Escaping is only needed in *string literals in your code*. If you print `argv[1]` character-by-character, you will get the string as is.

```
std::cout << argv[1];
```

If you are not getting the correct result, this means escaped sequences are first processed *by the shell*. You can avoid it in many shell. E.g. in bash you have to pass your argument with single quotes:

```
bash$ ./program 'd""\"/""b'
```